# How to create custom sanitize_title() function like WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a script where I want to use the WordPress sanitize_title function to generate slugs, without loading its entire library (WordPress is too slow).

Is there any way to get the source of this function to make it work in my own code without loading WordPress?

at the moment I found this in the wordpress code, but this calls wordpress dependeces:

```
function sanitize_title( $title, $fallback_title = '', $context = 'save' ) {
    $raw_title = $title;
 
    if ( 'save' === $context ) {
        $title = remove_accents( $title );
    }
 
    /**
     * Filters a sanitized title string.
     *
     * @since 1.2.0
     *
     * @param string $title     Sanitized title.
     * @param string $raw_title The title prior to sanitization.
     * @param string $context   The context for which the title is being sanitized.
     */
    $title = apply_filters( 'sanitize_title', $title, $raw_title, $context );
 
    if ( '' === $title || false === $title ) {
        $title = $fallback_title;
    }
 
    return $title;
}
```

any help is appreciated.

note: I don't wanna any other similar function.

Comment: if you don't want to recreate the function, you could include the libraries in wp that's required for that wp function to run. it'll still be clunky though and not guaranteed fat free. you'd still be loading a lot of files for a single function. i'd still take the similar route

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/how-to-load-wordpress-on-non-wp-page here's worth a try. it loads the core, just disable the theme loading and use your function like you normally do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the below functions that WordPress has to sanitize_title. you can find this all function in WordPress.

> I renamed these functions with `custom_` prefix.

```
function custom_sanitize_title( $title, $fallback_title = '', $context = 'save' ) {
    $raw_title = $title;
    if ( 'save' === $context ) {
        $title = custom_remove_accents( $title );
    }

    $title = custom_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title );

    if ( '' === $title || false === $title ) {
        $title = $fallback_title;
    }

    return $title;
}

function custom_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
    $title = strip_tags( $title );
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title );
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace( '%', '', $title );
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace( '|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title );

    if ( custom_seems_utf8( $title ) ) {
        if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) ) {
            $title = mb_strtolower( $title, 'UTF-8' );
        }
        $title = custom_utf8_uri_encode( $title, 200 );
    }

    $title = strtolower( $title );

    if ( 'save' === $context ) {
        // Convert &nbsp, &ndash, and &mdash to hyphens.
        $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );
        // Convert &nbsp, &ndash, and &mdash HTML entities to hyphens.
        $title = str_replace( array( '&nbsp;', '&#160;', '&ndash;', '&#8211;', '&mdash;', '&#8212;' ), '-', $title );
        // Convert forward slash to hyphen.
        $title = str_replace( '/', '-', $title );

        // Strip these characters entirely.
        $title = str_replace(
            array(
                // Soft hyphens.
                '%c2%ad',
                // &iexcl and &iquest.
                '%c2%a1',
                '%c2%bf',
                // Angle quotes.
                '%c2%ab',
                '%c2%bb',
                '%e2%80%b9',
                '%e2%80%ba',
                // Curly quotes.
                '%e2%80%98',
                '%e2%80%99',
                '%e2%80%9c',
                '%e2%80%9d',
                '%e2%80%9a',
                '%e2%80%9b',
                '%e2%80%9e',
                '%e2%80%9f',
                // Bullet.
                '%e2%80%a2',
                // &copy, &reg, &deg, &hellip, and &trade.
                '%c2%a9',
                '%c2%ae',
                '%c2%b0',
                '%e2%80%a6',
                '%e2%84%a2',
                // Acute accents.
                '%c2%b4',
                '%cb%8a',
                '%cc%81',
                '%cd%81',
                // Grave accent, macron, caron.
                '%cc%80',
                '%cc%84',
                '%cc%8c',
            ),
            '',
            $title
        );

        // Convert &times to 'x'.
        $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
    }

    // Kill entities.
    $title = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $title );
    $title = str_replace( '.', '-', $title );

    $title = preg_replace( '/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title );
    $title = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '-', $title );
    $title = preg_replace( '|-+|', '-', $title );
    $title = trim( $title, '-' );

    return $title;
}

function custom_remove_accents( $string ) {
    if ( ! preg_match( '/[\x80-\xff]/', $string ) ) {
        return $string;
    }

    if ( custom_seems_utf8( $string ) ) {
        $chars = array(
            // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement.
            'ª' => 'a',
            'º' => 'o',
            'À' => 'A',
            'Á' => 'A',
            'Â' => 'A',
            'Ã' => 'A',
            'Ä' => 'A',
            'Å' => 'A',
            'Æ' => 'AE',
            'Ç' => 'C',
            'È' => 'E',
            'É' => 'E',
            'Ê' => 'E',
            'Ë' => 'E',
            'Ì' => 'I',
            'Í' => 'I',
            'Î' => 'I',
            'Ï' => 'I',
            'Ð' => 'D',
            'Ñ' => 'N',
            'Ò' => 'O',
            'Ó' => 'O',
            'Ô' => 'O',
            'Õ' => 'O',
            'Ö' => 'O',
            'Ù' => 'U',
            'Ú' => 'U',
            'Û' => 'U',
            'Ü' => 'U',
            'Ý' => 'Y',
            'Þ' => 'TH',
            'ß' => 's',
            'à' => 'a',
            'á' => 'a',
            'â' => 'a',
            'ã' => 'a',
            'ä' => 'a',
            'å' => 'a',
            'æ' => 'ae',
            'ç' => 'c',
            'è' => 'e',
            'é' => 'e',
            'ê' => 'e',
            'ë' => 'e',
            'ì' => 'i',
            'í' => 'i',
            'î' => 'i',
            'ï' => 'i',
            'ð' => 'd',
            'ñ' => 'n',
            'ò' => 'o',
            'ó' => 'o',
            'ô' => 'o',
            'õ' => 'o',
            'ö' => 'o',
            'ø' => 'o',
            'ù' => 'u',
            'ú' => 'u',
            'û' => 'u',
            'ü' => 'u',
            'ý' => 'y',
            'þ' => 'th',
            'ÿ' => 'y',
            'Ø' => 'O',
            // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A.
            'Ā' => 'A',
            'ā' => 'a',
            'Ă' => 'A',
            'ă' => 'a',
            'Ą' => 'A',
            'ą' => 'a',
            'Ć' => 'C',
            'ć' => 'c',
            'Ĉ' => 'C',
            'ĉ' => 'c',
            'Ċ' => 'C',
            'ċ' => 'c',
            'Č' => 'C',
            'č' => 'c',
            'Ď' => 'D',
            'ď' => 'd',
            'Đ' => 'D',
            'đ' => 'd',
            'Ē' => 'E',
            'ē' => 'e',
            'Ĕ' => 'E',
            'ĕ' => 'e',
            'Ė' => 'E',
            'ė' => 'e',
            'Ę' => 'E',
            'ę' => 'e',
            'Ě' => 'E',
            'ě' => 'e',
            'Ĝ' => 'G',
            'ĝ' => 'g',
            'Ğ' => 'G',
            'ğ' => 'g',
            'Ġ' => 'G',
            'ġ' => 'g',
            'Ģ' => 'G',
            'ģ' => 'g',
            'Ĥ' => 'H',
            'ĥ' => 'h',
            'Ħ' => 'H',
            'ħ' => 'h',
            'Ĩ' => 'I',
            'ĩ' => 'i',
            'Ī' => 'I',
            'ī' => 'i',
            'Ĭ' => 'I',
            'ĭ' => 'i',
            'Į' => 'I',
            'į' => 'i',
            'İ' => 'I',
            'ı' => 'i',
            'Ĳ' => 'IJ',
            'ĳ' => 'ij',
            'Ĵ' => 'J',
            'ĵ' => 'j',
            'Ķ' => 'K',
            'ķ' => 'k',
            'ĸ' => 'k',
            'Ĺ' => 'L',
            'ĺ' => 'l',
            'Ļ' => 'L',
            'ļ' => 'l',
            'Ľ' => 'L',
            'ľ' => 'l',
            'Ŀ' => 'L',
            'ŀ' => 'l',
            'Ł' => 'L',
            'ł' => 'l',
            'Ń' => 'N',
            'ń' => 'n',
            'Ņ' => 'N',
            'ņ' => 'n',
            'Ň' => 'N',
            'ň' => 'n',
            'ŉ' => 'n',
            'Ŋ' => 'N',
            'ŋ' => 'n',
            'Ō' => 'O',
            'ō' => 'o',
            'Ŏ' => 'O',
            'ŏ' => 'o',
            'Ő' => 'O',
            'ő' => 'o',
            'Œ' => 'OE',
            'œ' => 'oe',
            'Ŕ' => 'R',
            'ŕ' => 'r',
            'Ŗ' => 'R',
            'ŗ' => 'r',
            'Ř' => 'R',
            'ř' => 'r',
            'Ś' => 'S',
            'ś' => 's',
            'Ŝ' => 'S',
            'ŝ' => 's',
            'Ş' => 'S',
            'ş' => 's',
            'Š' => 'S',
            'š' => 's',
            'Ţ' => 'T',
            'ţ' => 't',
            'Ť' => 'T',
            'ť' => 't',
            'Ŧ' => 'T',
            'ŧ' => 't',
            'Ũ' => 'U',
            'ũ' => 'u',
            'Ū' => 'U',
            'ū' => 'u',
            'Ŭ' => 'U',
            'ŭ' => 'u',
            'Ů' => 'U',
            'ů' => 'u',
            'Ű' => 'U',
            'ű' => 'u',
            'Ų' => 'U',
            'ų' => 'u',
            'Ŵ' => 'W',
            'ŵ' => 'w',
            'Ŷ' => 'Y',
            'ŷ' => 'y',
            'Ÿ' => 'Y',
            'Ź' => 'Z',
            'ź' => 'z',
            'Ż' => 'Z',
            'ż' => 'z',
            'Ž' => 'Z',
            'ž' => 'z',
            'ſ' => 's',
            // Decompositions for Latin Extended-B.
            'Ș' => 'S',
            'ș' => 's',
            'Ț' => 'T',
            'ț' => 't',
            // Euro sign.
            '€' => 'E',
            // GBP (Pound) sign.
            '£' => '',
            // Vowels with diacritic (Vietnamese).
            // Unmarked.
            'Ơ' => 'O',
            'ơ' => 'o',
            'Ư' => 'U',
            'ư' => 'u',
            // Grave accent.
            'Ầ' => 'A',
            'ầ' => 'a',
            'Ằ' => 'A',
            'ằ' => 'a',
            'Ề' => 'E',
            'ề' => 'e',
            'Ồ' => 'O',
            'ồ' => 'o',
            'Ờ' => 'O',
            'ờ' => 'o',
            'Ừ' => 'U',
            'ừ' => 'u',
            'Ỳ' => 'Y',
            'ỳ' => 'y',
            // Hook.
            'Ả' => 'A',
            'ả' => 'a',
            'Ẩ' => 'A',
            'ẩ' => 'a',
            'Ẳ' => 'A',
            'ẳ' => 'a',
            'Ẻ' => 'E',
            'ẻ' => 'e',
            'Ể' => 'E',
            'ể' => 'e',
            'Ỉ' => 'I',
            'ỉ' => 'i',
            'Ỏ' => 'O',
            'ỏ' => 'o',
            'Ổ' => 'O',
            'ổ' => 'o',
            'Ở' => 'O',
            'ở' => 'o',
            'Ủ' => 'U',
            'ủ' => 'u',
            'Ử' => 'U',
            'ử' => 'u',
            'Ỷ' => 'Y',
            'ỷ' => 'y',
            // Tilde.
            'Ẫ' => 'A',
            'ẫ' => 'a',
            'Ẵ' => 'A',
            'ẵ' => 'a',
            'Ẽ' => 'E',
            'ẽ' => 'e',
            'Ễ' => 'E',
            'ễ' => 'e',
            'Ỗ' => 'O',
            'ỗ' => 'o',
            'Ỡ' => 'O',
            'ỡ' => 'o',
            'Ữ' => 'U',
            'ữ' => 'u',
            'Ỹ' => 'Y',
            'ỹ' => 'y',
            // Acute accent.
            'Ấ' => 'A',
            'ấ' => 'a',
            'Ắ' => 'A',
            'ắ' => 'a',
            'Ế' => 'E',
            'ế' => 'e',
            'Ố' => 'O',
            'ố' => 'o',
            'Ớ' => 'O',
            'ớ' => 'o',
            'Ứ' => 'U',
            'ứ' => 'u',
            // Dot below.
            'Ạ' => 'A',
            'ạ' => 'a',
            'Ậ' => 'A',
            'ậ' => 'a',
            'Ặ' => 'A',
            'ặ' => 'a',
            'Ẹ' => 'E',
            'ẹ' => 'e',
            'Ệ' => 'E',
            'ệ' => 'e',
            'Ị' => 'I',
            'ị' => 'i',
            'Ọ' => 'O',
            'ọ' => 'o',
            'Ộ' => 'O',
            'ộ' => 'o',
            'Ợ' => 'O',
            'ợ' => 'o',
            'Ụ' => 'U',
            'ụ' => 'u',
            'Ự' => 'U',
            'ự' => 'u',
            'Ỵ' => 'Y',
            'ỵ' => 'y',
            // Vowels with diacritic (Chinese, Hanyu Pinyin).
            'ɑ' => 'a',
            // Macron.
            'Ǖ' => 'U',
            'ǖ' => 'u',
            // Acute accent.
            'Ǘ' => 'U',
            'ǘ' => 'u',
            // Caron.
            'Ǎ' => 'A',
            'ǎ' => 'a',
            'Ǐ' => 'I',
            'ǐ' => 'i',
            'Ǒ' => 'O',
            'ǒ' => 'o',
            'Ǔ' => 'U',
            'ǔ' => 'u',
            'Ǚ' => 'U',
            'ǚ' => 'u',
            // Grave accent.
            'Ǜ' => 'U',
            'ǜ' => 'u',
        );

        $string = strtr( $string, $chars );
    } else {
        $chars = array();
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8.
        $chars['in'] = "\x80\x83\x8a\x8e\x9a\x9e"
            . "\x9f\xa2\xa5\xb5\xc0\xc1\xc2"
            . "\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca"
            . "\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd1\xd2"
            . "\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd8\xd9\xda"
            . "\xdb\xdc\xdd\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3"
            . "\xe4\xe5\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb"
            . "\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf1\xf2\xf3"
            . "\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb"
            . "\xfc\xfd\xff";

        $chars['out'] = 'EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy';

        $string              = strtr( $string, $chars['in'], $chars['out'] );
        $double_chars        = array();
        $double_chars['in']  = array( "\x8c", "\x9c", "\xc6", "\xd0", "\xde", "\xdf", "\xe6", "\xf0", "\xfe" );
        $double_chars['out'] = array( 'OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th' );
        $string              = str_replace( $double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string );
    }

    return $string;
}


function custom_seems_utf8( $str ) {
    custom_mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
    $length = strlen( $str );
    custom_reset_mbstring_encoding();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $c = ord( $str[ $i ] );
        if ( $c < 0x80 ) {
            $n = 0; // 0bbbbbbb
        } elseif ( ( $c & 0xE0 ) == 0xC0 ) {
            $n = 1; // 110bbbbb
        } elseif ( ( $c & 0xF0 ) == 0xE0 ) {
            $n = 2; // 1110bbbb
        } elseif ( ( $c & 0xF8 ) == 0xF0 ) {
            $n = 3; // 11110bbb
        } elseif ( ( $c & 0xFC ) == 0xF8 ) {
            $n = 4; // 111110bb
        } elseif ( ( $c & 0xFE ) == 0xFC ) {
            $n = 5; // 1111110b
        } else {
            return false; // Does not match any model.
        }
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $n; $j++ ) { // n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ( ( ++$i == $length ) || ( ( ord( $str[ $i ] ) & 0xC0 ) != 0x80 ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function custom_mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( $reset = false ) {
    static $encodings  = array();
    static $overloaded = null;

    if ( is_null( $overloaded ) ) {
        $overloaded = function_exists( 'mb_internal_encoding' ); // phpcs:ignore PHPCompatibility.IniDirectives.RemovedIniDirectives.mbstring_func_overloadDeprecated
    }

    if ( false === $overloaded ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $reset ) {
        $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
        array_push( $encodings, $encoding );
        mb_internal_encoding( 'ISO-8859-1' );
    }

    if ( $reset && $encodings ) {
        $encoding = array_pop( $encodings );
        mb_internal_encoding( $encoding );
    }
}

function custom_reset_mbstring_encoding() {
    custom_mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( true );
}

function custom_utf8_uri_encode( $utf8_string, $length = 0 ) {
    $unicode        = '';
    $values         = array();
    $num_octets     = 1;
    $unicode_length = 0;

    custom_mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
    $string_length = strlen( $utf8_string );
    custom_reset_mbstring_encoding();

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++ ) {

        $value = ord( $utf8_string[ $i ] );

        if ( $value < 128 ) {
            if ( $length && ( $unicode_length >= $length ) ) {
                break;
            }
            $unicode .= chr( $value );
            $unicode_length++;
        } else {
            if ( count( $values ) == 0 ) {
                if ( $value < 224 ) {
                    $num_octets = 2;
                } elseif ( $value < 240 ) {
                    $num_octets = 3;
                } else {
                    $num_octets = 4;
                }
            }

            $values[] = $value;

            if ( $length && ( $unicode_length + ( $num_octets * 3 ) ) > $length ) {
                break;
            }
            if ( count( $values ) == $num_octets ) {
                for ( $j = 0; $j < $num_octets; $j++ ) {
                    $unicode .= '%' . dechex( $values[ $j ] );
                }

                $unicode_length += $num_octets * 3;

                $values     = array();
                $num_octets = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $unicode;
}
```

Call function

```
echo custom_sanitize_title('This is custom title');
```

Output

```
this-is-custom-title
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9202e930361634fd229f8d32215aa2036fbd9959)